# AJAX call not firing on ipad but fine on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax

I have the following custom plugin code

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.createGallery = function(options) {
        var theObject = $(this);
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            server: 'http://localhost/jQuery%20Gallery/images/galleries/homepage_gallery',
            galleryName: 'Test',
            galleryWidth: theObject.parent().width(),
            galleryImageMargin: 20,
            galleryImageColumns: 2,
            imageQuality: 100
        }, options);

        var galleryImageWidth = settings.galleryWidth / settings.galleryImageColumns;
        var imageUrl = settings.server;

        var otherMargin = Math.round(settings.galleryImageMargin / 2);
        var finalImageWidth = Math.round(galleryImageWidth - settings.galleryImageMargin);
        var finalImageHeight = Math.round(galleryImageWidth / 1.4);
        var finalGalleryWidth = settings.galleryWidth - settings.galleryImageMargin;

        $(this).before('<style>'+$(this).selector+' li:nth-child('+settings.galleryImageColumns+'n+1) { margin-left: 0; } '+$(this).selector+' li:first-child { margin-left: 0; } '+$(this).selector+' { width: '+finalGalleryWidth+'px; margin: 0px; } '+$(this).selector+' li { display: inline-block; list-style: none; margin-left: '+settings.galleryImageMargin+'px; margin-bottom: '+otherMargin+'px; } </style>');

        $.ajax({
            url: imageUrl,
            success: function(data){
                console.log('SUCCESS');
                var extension = '.jpg';
                $(data).find("a:contains("+extension+")").each(function(){
                    // will loop through 
                    var filename = $(this).attr("href");
                    $('<li></li>').html('<a href="'+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'" class="fancybox"><img src="thumbnail.php?src='+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'&q='+settings.imageQuality+'&h='+finalImageHeight+'&w='+finalImageWidth+'"/></a>').appendTo(theObject);
                });
                theObject.children('li:nth-child('+settings.galleryImageColumns+'n+1)').addClass('triggerMarginIE8');
            },
            failure: function(data){
                console.log('FAIL');
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This works fine on my desktop as far as I can tell. Yet the AJAX doesn't fire properly on iOS devices (and possibly other devices) or a colleague's machine, it says the folder has been permanently moved, but it hasn't!

Any ideas? I know when the AJAX is running or not because of the `console.log`

Comment: Tried with a relative path for the url? Especially if you have something like a base href declared in your meta tags it can screw up some JavaScript urls depending on the device.

Comment: so i should just try images/galleries/homepage_gallery/ ?

Comment: Mind if I put that as an answer now when it's confirmed in case others have same issue? I know I had before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting in a relative path in the url. :)

```
   server: 'images/galleries/homepage_gallery', //your relative path...
   var imageUrl = settings.server;

   //Ajax call
   $.ajax({
        url: imageUrl,
        success: function(data){
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            var extension = '.jpg';
            $(data).find("a:contains("+extension+")").each(function(){
                // will loop through 
                var filename = $(this).attr("href");
                $('<li></li>').html('<a href="'+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'" class="fancybox"><img src="thumbnail.php?src='+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'&q='+settings.imageQuality+'&h='+finalImageHeight+'&w='+finalImageWidth+'"/></a>').appendTo(theObject);
            });
            theObject.children('li:nth-child('+settings.galleryImageColumns+'n+1)').addClass('triggerMarginIE8');
        },
        failure: function(data){
            console.log('FAIL');
        }
    });
```